# Webscraping over multiple pages in R

Tags: html, r, loops, web-scraping

I would like to set up a loop to automate some webscraping across multiple pages. So far, this is the code I have for one iteration:

```
s <- html_session("https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/resultados-buscador.html?")
s <- s %>% jump_to("?pagina=5") %>% read_html()
new <- s %>% html_nodes('div.dp-metadata span') %>% html_text()
type.2 <- s %>% html_nodes('h4') %>% html_text()
title <- s %>% html_nodes('div.dp-texto') %>% html_text()



new <- gsub("Iniciado en: ", "", new)
new <- gsub("Fecha: ", "", new)
new <- gsub("Expediente Diputados:", "", new)
new <- gsub("Expediente Senado:", "", new)
new<- new [-c(3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79)]
chamber <- new[c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58)]
billnum <- new[c(2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53, 56, 59)]
fecha <- new[c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60)]


new2 <- data.frame(chamber, billnum, fecha, title, type.2)
```

The part that should change is the number after "pagina=". However, I tried to create the following simplified loop and it just returned an error:

```
new4 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=40, ncol=2))
colnames(new4) <- c("title", "type")

for (i in 1:2) {
s <- html_session("https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/resultados-buscador.html?")
s <- s %>% jump_to("?pagina=", i) %>% read_html()
type.2 <- s %>% html_nodes('h4') %>% html_text()
title <- s %>% html_nodes('div.dp-texto') %>% html_text()



new4[i, 1] <- title
new4[i, 2] <- type.2

}
```

Again, this simplified loop that only scrapes two of the five features I need does not work and returns an error: Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : is.request(y) is not TRUE. I imagine there is something wrong with running the html_session() and jump_to() commands in a loop. I would like to know how to automate this in a loop to avoid scraping several thousands of pages by hand.

I've even attempted creating a vector using lapply, but I'm not super confident in my coding of functions and all of the templates I've seen are simple read_html() commands and I'm not quite sure how I would incorporate the html_session() and jump_to() commands into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. The main issue in your code is at `jump_to("?pagina=", i)`...This should be `jump_to(paste0("?pagina=", i))`. Here's a full solution:

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

sesh <- html_session("https://www.hcdn.gob.ar/proyectos/resultados-buscador.html?")

scrape_one_page <- function(sesh, i) {
  one_page <- sesh %>% jump_to(paste0("?pagina=", i)) %>% read_html()
  new <- one_page %>% html_nodes('div.dp-metadata span') %>% html_text()
  type.2 <- one_page %>% html_nodes('h4') %>% html_text()
  title <- one_page %>% html_nodes('div.dp-texto') %>% html_text()

  new <- gsub("Iniciado en: ", "", new)
  new <- gsub("Fecha: ", "", new)
  new <- gsub("Expediente Diputados:", "", new)
  new <- gsub("Expediente Senado:", "", new)
  new <- new [-c(3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79)]
  chamber <- new[c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52, 55, 58)]
  billnum <- new[c(2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53, 56, 59)]
  fecha <- new[c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60)]

  data.frame(chamber, billnum, fecha, title, type.2, stringsAsFactors = F)
}

# This call to lapply basically says:
# ...For each element in 1:5 (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
#   ...call scrape_one_page() with the first argument being equal to one of those elements and with the argument `sesh` equal to `sesh`
# ... then put the results in a list

# so it basically results in: 
# outs <- list(
#  scrap_one_page(1, sesh),
#  scrap_one_page(2, sesh),
#  scrap_one_page(3, sesh),
#  scrap_one_page(4, sesh),
#  scrap_one_page(5, sesh)
# )
outs <- lapply(1:5, scrape_one_page, sesh = sesh)

# then here with do.call(rbind) we combine the list of data frames into a single data frame 
df <- do.call(rbind, outs)

# and finally print the first few rows of the data frame
head(df)
#>     chamber      billnum      fecha
#> 1 Diputados  3967-D-2018 29/06/2018
#> 2 Diputados  3966-D-2018 29/06/2018
#> 3 Diputados  3965-D-2018 29/06/2018
#> 4 Diputados  3964-D-2018 29/06/2018
#> 5 Diputados  3963-D-2018 29/06/2018
#> 6 Diputados  3962-D-2018 29/06/2018
#>                                                                                                                                     title
#> 1 SOLICITAR AL PODER EJECUTIVO DISPONGA LAS MEDIDAS NECESARIAS PARA ASEGURAR LA CONTINUIDAD DEL CICLO LECTIVO EN LA PROVINCIA DEL CHUBUT.
#> 2                                                         EXPRESAR REPUDIO POR LA POLITICA INMIGRATORIA DE LOS ESTADOS UNIDOS DE AMERICA.
#> 3                  EXPRESAR REPUDIO POR EL FRAUDE COMETIDO EL 23 DE JUNIO 2018 EN LA "FEDERACION UNIVERSITARIA DE BUENOS AIRES - FUBA -".
#> 4                         EXPRESAR REPUDIO POR LA REPRESION DE FUERZAS POLICIALES Y DE SEGURIDAD, CONTRA LOS TRABAJADORES DE CRESTA ROJA.
#> 5                          PROHIBENSE LOS DESPIDOS DE LA AGENCIA DE NOTICIAS ESTATAL TELAM S.E. POR EL TERMINO DE 24 MESES PRORROGABLES. 
#> 6              DECLARESE LA SEMANA QUE CONTIENE EL 26 DE JUNIO DE CADA AÑO COMO "SEMANA NACIONAL DE LA PREVENCION DEL CONSUMO DE DROGAS".
#>                   type.2
#> 1 PROYECTO DE RESOLUCIÓN
#> 2 PROYECTO DE RESOLUCIÓN
#> 3 PROYECTO DE RESOLUCIÓN
#> 4 PROYECTO DE RESOLUCIÓN
#> 5        PROYECTO DE LEY
#> 6        PROYECTO DE LEY
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the code is very straightforward and does exactly what I need it to. I feel rather silly for not including the paste0() command. Would you mind walking through each step of what this code is doing, I would really appreciate a full understanding as I am very new to coding.

Comment: you wrote most of the code, didn't you? if so, i image you know what's going on with it?

Comment: Yes, I did. I was just referencing the first part of the function (scrape_one_page) and the lapply section at the end. The main part of the function makes sense to me as that was part of the original code I wrote.

Comment: there ya go, hope that helps